# Resolve Ip address from hostname for other devices connected through wifi network android programmatically

Tags: android, web-services, wifi, hostname, inetaddress

From my testing android device i want to get IP address through host name of particular device  connected through wife network this below code runs fine in some testing android devices but in other devices its give me UnknownHostException, Why it is not resolving IP address in some devices?

```
InetAddress inetaddress=InetAddress.getByName("HostName");
System.out.println("address="+inetaddress.getHostAddress());
```

Code for searching ip address from DNS server -

```
  AsyncTaskRunner runner;
  DhcpInfo d;
public void resolveIp(){
    WifiManager wifii = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    d = wifii.getDhcpInfo();
    runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute();
}
public String intToIP(int i) {
    System.out.println("i="+i);
    String ip= ((i & 0xFF) + "." + ((i >> 8) & 0xFF) +
            "." + ((i >> 16) & 0xFF) + "." + ((i >> 24) & 0xFF));
    System.out.println("ip="+ip);
    return ip;
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    InetAddress host;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
                    String ddns1 = intToIP(d.dns1);
            host = InetAddress.getByName(ddns1);
            byte[]ip= host.getAddress();
            for (int j = 1; j <= 254; j++){
                ip[2]=(byte)j;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++) {
                ip[3] = (byte) i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
                    System.out.println("address="+address.getHostName()+" "+address.getHostAddress());
                }
            }
        }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

}
```

can anyone optimize this code?

Comment: there is app that do same thing get ip address and hostname of my wifi network i want like that- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en

Comment: do you got answer? i have also same problem.

Comment: I got IP addresses and mac addresses of connected devices. but still i am stucking to get hostname of particular devices. If you get answer let me know. thanks

Comment: i am getting ip address if use proper hostname like "xyz.abc.com" but for direct name xyz it gives me exception in some devices note -in some devices only otherwise i am getting ip address properly. @sam